# How to use integer number to substitute float number and losing less precision and efficiency?

Tags: algorithm, integer, floating-point, mobile-phones

Because the aim compile platform(MTK) does not support float number, and it is very slow when MTK simulate float operation, I must use some other objects to substitute the float. Is integer a good choice? Or implement a Float Class using String? Is there any libs to solve this problem? Thanks for your advice;-)

Comment: Not sure about the platform you are working, but would be possible to outperform existing simulation which probably is implemented as efficiently as possible?

Comment: why would your float emulator be better than the systems? And how could string ever be performant?

Comment: Float Class is not a good idea, and I will try some other way

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider fixed point numbers, or else a rational integer package. Implementing a Float class yourself is going to be slower than the simulated float operations.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

Multiply everything by 10, 100, 1000, 10000 depending on the resolution you need.

Then just do fixed point math

For example, using 10000

10000/2 = 5000, or .5

Since most signed integers are up to 2 Billion, that can give you a lot of room for decimals.

If you need transcendental functions, use look up tables.